# Django 1.6 annotate on reverse field and condition

Tags: django, django-models

I want to annotate on a remote model (traversing the 2 model relationship) based on the remote model's field only if it is false. Is this possible?

```
foo = CommunityProfile.objects.annotate(answered_count=Count('threadvault__unanswered'=False))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter the queryset first, then annotate.

```
profiles = CommunityProfile.objects.filter(
    threadvault__unanswered=False
).annotate(
    answered_count=Count('threadvault')
)
```